# Python 3 extract html data from sports site

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract data from a sports site and so far failing. I am Trying to extract the 35, Shots on Goal and 23 but have been failing.

```html
<div class="statTextGroup">
   <div class="statText statText--homeValue">35</div>
   <div class="statText statText--titleValue">Shots on Goal</div>
   <div class="statText statText--awayValue">23</div></div>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get("https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/match/lvbns58C/#match-statistics;0")
src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

stats = soup.find("div", {"class": "tab-statistics-0-statistic"})
print(stats)
```

This is the code I have been trying to use and when I run it I get "None" printed to me. Could someone help me so I can print out the data.

Full page found here: https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/match/lvbns58C/#match-statistics;0

Comment: https://d.scoreboard.com/uk/x/feed/d_st_lvbns58C_en-uk_1 will return the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the website is rendered by javascript, possible option would load the page using selenium and then parse it with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# initialize selenium driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('<<PATH_TO_SELENIUMDRIVER>>', options=chrome_options)

# load page via selenium
wd.get("https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/match/lvbns58C/#match-statistics;0")

# wait 30 seconds until element with class mainGrid will be loaded
table = WebDriverWait(wd, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'statistics-content')))

# parse content of the table
soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser')

print(soup)

# close selenium driver
wd.quit()
```